# Emulator runs distorted xml layout than that of the one in eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout

I have searched the site for answers however I could not find something as all the cases seem not to have an answer that will work for me.

Basically when I run the app on my phone the layout is different than the one I have set up in Eclipse.

I have tried this in the manifest android:configChanges="screenSize" however I have no success. I also have set all my size as dp.

Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks!

This is my xml(for the portrait layout, but the problem is on both)

```
'<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:background="@drawable/sothisisart"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Convert from: "
     android:textSize="@dimen/activity_larger"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvConvertFrom"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="type here" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbKilometers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="@dimen/activity_larger2"
        android:text="Kilometers" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbMiles"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="@dimen/activity_larger2"
        android:text="Miles" />


</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvConvertFrom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bConvert"
    android:text= ""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAnswer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bConvert"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
     android:textSize="@dimen/activity_larger"
    android:text=" "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bConvert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:text="Convert"
    android:textSize="@dimen/activity_larger" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvAnswer"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvAnswer"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bConvert"
    android:text="Equals:"
     android:textSize="@dimen/activity_larger"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>'
```

And I'm not sure if its needed but this is AndroidManifest

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.daniel.kilometermilecoverter"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/mileconverter"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.daniel.kilometermilecoverter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">          
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

 </manifest>'
```

Comment: Can you post your layout?

Comment: so it looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51806645/2013-06-26_16-07-11.jpg) what's the ideal one?